# DateTimeFormatter formatting failure

Tags: java-8

I'm writing a until tests to test the validity of a license key.. and at the same time, updating the code to use the java 8 java.time package.

So.. creating a 'valid until' datetime and formatting that to a string:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());
LocalDateTime nowPlus1Hour = now.plusHours(1);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
formatter = formatter.withZone(Clock.systemUTC().getZone());
String validUntilString = nowPlus1Hour.format(formatter);
```

This.. mostly works. (My last version threw an exception because I wasn't creating a formatter 'withZone'.)

However, the value of 'validUntilString' is '2015-05-19 19:46:26 Z'  Really.  'Z'.  C'mon!

So.. given a LocalDateTime, how do you get a string that includes the (yes, ambigious, but in this case UTC, a standard) time zone id?

Comment: Z is a synonym for UTC. What you have looks fine to me. See http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones

Comment: Well.. now don't I feel silly.

Comment: Z stands for Zulu time

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  JB Nizet, if you'll 'answer' this, I'll give you the big green checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, the time zone is already included in your string :

`"2015-05-19 19:46:26 Z"`

This letter `Z` is coming from a [military - NATO convention](http://www.world-timezone.com/military-nato-letter-timezones/)

> The basis for this is Z – Zulu time – Zero meridian time – the same as UTC It’s a convention to assign letters to time zones, where Z= Zero meridian, and Zulu is the word that represents the letter Z, when it’s used in communication. It is sometimes used in the US Military and NATO in conjunction with 24 hour clocks, and is also popular to use in movies to reference time.
>
> Other letters/words are used for other time zones than UTC.....

Read the [cited reference](http://www.world-timezone.com/military-nato-letter-timezones/) for full details.